# QGIS, Grid, and CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I'm totally lost after some manipulations to add a grid in QGIS.

The projection of my project is WGS84 3857. It's a map of UK.

I tried *View>Decorations>Grid* option. Everytime I get a perfect squared grid and I find it suspicious. I tried with WGS84 3857 and 4326.

So I tried the *Print layout's* method to add a grid. And here I'm more confused: 
with WGS84 3857 it's not what I want (perfectly squared with 3857 coordinates in metres)
BUT in WGS84 4326, it seems relevant (rectangles with degrees coordinates).

So here is my question: What is the right way to have relevant grid in QGIS ?

EDIT: Here is a more precise question:

[image]

Comment: please edit your question to show a picture of the issues you are having. What sort of grid do you actually want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPSG:3857 uses the Mercator projection and the latitude and longitude lines are straight and form rectangles. Both a grid using projected coordinates and a graticule using latitude-longitude values (EPSG:4326) will be rectangular.

Here's an image of EPSG:3857 with a 10° by 10° degree graticule superimposed on it. A grid of the projected units would be perfectly square if you used the same spacing in both x (easting) and y (northing). Map was done in ArcGIS but it'll be the same in QGIS.

[image: World map displayed in EPSG:3857 with a 10x10 deg graticule]

Comment: Yeah, so why do I have squares for result...

Comment: Do you mean as opposed to rectangles? That will depend on where the data is. I've added a picture.

Comment: It's a map of UK, that's why I know there is a problem with my grid :D

Comment: Are you sure you want to use 3857 and not 27700? 227700 is British National Grid.

Comment: My quesiton is not about what is the right projection here : I use osm tiles so I prefer to stay in 3857.
As example, I actually would like to have that grid, on this projection : http://map.openseamap.org/

But I got this squares problem :'(

Comment: Okay, but you're going to get squares if you create a grid using the projected coordinates (unless the x/y spacings are different) and you're going to get the same if you add a graticule, again depending on the spacing. Maybe add a picture or 2 to the question so we can see what you're seeing or a picture of what you expect to see (from an existing map maybe).

Comment: And include the exact parameter values you're using when you create the grids.